# Neo4J Create query using values from previous query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

On Neo4j, you can get a list of node labels and relationships with the query:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)

RETURN DISTINCT head(labels(a)) AS This, type(r) as To, head(labels(b)) AS That;
```

Which results in:

```
This    To  That

Person  ACTED_IN    Movie

Person  DIRECTED    Movie

Person  PRODUCED    Movie
```

I want to turn the resulting table into a graph (something like `(Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(Movie))`. How can I add a create statement to the query above to use labels(a) and labels(b) for the nodes and type(r) for the relationships?

Comment: I don't think relationship type can be resolved from an expression, it must be declared literally in the query; which means it must be know beforehand. I've never seen any hack for this in cypher either, though it should be easy to do in the Java API (or any other API) by dynamically constructing a second query based on the results.

Comment: Agree with @jjaderberg; you can generically use a CREATE statement to create a new graph on the basis of whatever you pull out of an existing graph with MATCH, but I don't think you can create a new relationship with a label whose value is derived from one of those variables.   Best to go the java route.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Thanks for the comments, guys.

Comment: you can also create literal create statements from cypher as strings. or use my github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools to export your cypher results to csv and then import the same csv with the necessary create statements but the special create (:#{label}) syntx